# Dynamically Disable FormArray in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, formarray, formgroups

I have multiple checkboxes as a FormArray. When page load I want to disable all those checkboxes.

I tried in the below mentioned way but it didn't work.

Can someone please explain me on this?

**.ts file**

```
public myForm: FormGroup = new FormGroup({
    name: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
    specialized: new FormArray([]),
  });

ngOnInit(): void {
      this.companyForm.controls['specialized'].disable();
}

  get myFormArray() {
    return this.myForm.controls.specialized as FormArray;
  }

  private addCheckboxesToForm() {
    this.specilizedArea.forEach(() => this.myFormArray.push(new FormControl(false)));
  }
```

**.html file**

```
<form [formGroup]="myForm">
    <div class="form-check col-md-6"
                                *ngFor="let order of myFormArray.controls; let i = index">
    
                                <label formArrayName="specialized">
                                    <input type="checkbox" [formControlName]="i">
                                    {{specilizedArea[i]?.description}}
                                </label>
    
                            </div>
     <button (click)="saveCompany()"> ADD</button>
    </form>
```

Comment: Can you share your entire HTML form as well as all of the pertinent form code in the component class?

Comment: Hi @PaulThorsen. I added the html form and the component is already there.

Comment: Is that the entire component class? Where are `specilizedArea` and `companyForm` initialized? What does `saveCompany()` look like?

Comment: In addCheckboxesToForm method did you try to initialize it with disabled: true? Like this: new FormControl({value: false, disabled: true})

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `ngOnInit` you need to call method `addCheckboxesToForm` and inside that method just create FormControls with `disabled: true` property, it should look like this:

```
private addCheckboxesToForm() {
    this.specilizedArea.forEach(() => this.myFormArray.push(new FormControl({value: false, disabled: true})));
  }
```

Here is quick example that I created with your code: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-bmnfcd?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: Thank you for the prompt response. :) It's working now.